# How to store/load username in Grails app?

Tags: session, grails, shiro

I have a Grails (2.3.6) app that requires users to login before they can access the app. As soon as they login successfully, they are redirected to a landing page that displays their username in the top-right corner. I had this working nicely (or so I thought) with the following 3 pieces of code:

```
// myapp/grails-app/realms/myapp/MyAppRealm.groovy:
class MyAppRealm {
    def onSuccessfulLogin(Principal principal) {
        // Lots of code

        // If I logged in successfully with a username of "user1", then principal.name will be "user1" here.
        UserHolder.name = principal.name

        // Lots more code
    }
}
```

In the above code the `onSuccessfulLogin()` method is executed if the authentication layer determines they logged in successfully. The `principal.name` value is the authenticated username they logged in with. As you can see I store this value in a `UserHolder` POGO which looks like:

```
class UserHolder {
    static String name = null

    static String getName() {
        name
    }

    static void setName(String n) {
        name = n
    }
}
```

Then, in my GSP file:

```
// myapp/grails-app/views/page.gsp
You are logged in as ${UserHolder?.name}.
```

It was just reported to me that a tester logged in successfully, and a few minutes later, hit F5 and refreshed their screen, only to find that their username belonged to another tester! After looking at the code, the reason for this is obvious: `UserHolder.name` is a static variable; only 1 instance of it will live on the server at any given point in time. So if `user1` logs in, they'll see `user1` as their username in the UI. But if `user2` then logs in, `User.name` now equals `user2`, and if `user1` refreshes their screen, they'll see `user2` as their username.

So my next thought was to try and store `principal.name` in a session variable like `session.name = principal.name`:

```
// myapp/grails-app/realms/myapp/MyAppRealm.groovy:
class MyAppRealm {
    def onSuccessfulLogin(Principal principal) {
        // Lots of code

        // If I logged in successfully with a username of "user1", then principal.name will be "user1" here.
        session.name = principal.name

        // Lots more code
    }
}
```

...and then refer to it in the GSP like `You are logged in as ${session.name}.`. The problem there is that I don't have access to `session` from inside `MyAppRealm.groovy`, and it's not easily injectable (unless anyone can think of how). So I ask: how can I "record" `principal.name` over in `MyAppRealm`, and then specify the correct username from inside the GSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement in my Groovy and Grails app.Not really a direct answer to your solution but you can try something similar. This is what I did:

```
class UserController {

def register() {
    if(request.method == 'POST') {
        def u = new User()
        u.properties[
                    'login',
                    'password',
                    'firstName',
                    'lastName',
                    ] = params

         if(u.save()) {
            session.user = u
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1)
            redirect(controller: "myController", action: "welcome")
                }
}
```

And in my view, I used it  as follows:

```
Welcome ${session?.user?.firstName}
```

My User domain class is as follows:

```
class User {
    String login
    String password
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple is to use a TagLib. Here is the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#taglibs)

Below, you'll find a small example, using Spring Security Core:

```
class ProfileTagLib {

    def springSecurityService
    static namespace = "prf"
    static defaultEncodeAs = 'none'

    def username = { attrs, body ->

    def loggedInUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
    if(loggedInUser) {
        loggedInUser.attach()
        out << loggedInUser.firstName
    }
}
```

On my gsp, the next tag is the only thing I need to display the firstName:

```
<prf:username />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can access the username directly using the `spring-security-core` taglib `<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username"/>`

Comment: That's true, but on my project, I have to display the firstName, and not the username.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are answers posted above, but you can pretty much access the session inside your realm. This is the case where you don't have access to sessions in somewhere in the file.

```
// Import this package.
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder

// And then get the current session
def session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
```